# How to make awk command run faster on large data files

Tags: bash, performance, shell, awk

I used this `awk` command below to create a new UUID column in a table in my existing `.dat` files.

```
$ awk '("uuidgen" | getline uuid) > 0 {print uuid "|" $0} {close("uuidgen")}' $filename > ${filename}.pk
```

The problem is that my `.dat` files are pretty big (like 50-60 GB) and this `awk` command takes hours even on small data files (like 15MB).

Is there any way to increase the speed of this `awk` command?

Comment: please provide some lines from your .dat file

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you might save time by not having awk open and close `uuidgen` every line.

```
$ function regen() { while true; do uuidgen; done; }
$ coproc regen
$ awk -v f="$filename" '!(getline line < f){exit} {print $0,line}' OFS="|" < /dev/fd/${COPROC[0]} > "$filename".pk
```

This has awk reading your "real" filename from a variable, and the uuid from stdin, because the call to uuidgen is handled by a bash "[coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html)". The funky bit around the `getline` is to tell awk to quit once it runs out of input from `$filename`. Also, note that awk is taking input from input redirection instead of reading the file directly. This is important; the file descriptor at `/dev/fd/##` is a *bash* thing, and awk can't open it.

This should theoretically save you time doing unnecessary system calls to open, run and close the `uuidgen` binary. On the other hand, the coprocess is doing almost the same thing anyway by running `uuidgen` in a loop. Perhaps you'll see some improvement in an SMP environment. I don't have a 50GB text file handy for benchmarking. I'd love to hear your results.

Note that `coproc` is a feature that was introduced with bash version 4. And use of `/dev/fd/*` requires that bash is compiled with file descriptor support. In my system, it also means I have to make sure [`fdescfs(5)`](http://man.freebsd.org/fdescfs) is mounted.

---

I just noticed the following on my system (FreeBSD 11):

```
$ /bin/uuidgen -
usage: uuidgen [-1] [-n count] [-o filename]
```

If your `uuidgen` also has a `-n` option, then adding it to your `regen()` function with ANY value might be a useful optimization, to reduce the number of times the command needs to be reopened.  For example:

```
$ function regen() { while true; do uuidgen -n 100; done; }
```

This would result in uuidgen being called only once every 100 lines of input, rather than for every line.

---

And if you're running Linux, depending on how you're set up, you may have an alternate source for UUIDs.  Note:

```
$ awk -v f=/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid '{getline u<f; close(f); print u,$0}' OFS="|" "$filename" "$filename".pk
```

This doesn't require the bash `coproc`, it just has awk read a random uuid directly from a Linux kernel function that provides them. You're still closing the file handle for every line of input, but at least you don't have to exec the uuidgen binary.

YMMV. I don't know what OS you're running, so I don't know what's likely to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is calling shell to call awk to call shell to call uuidgen. Awk is a tool for manipulating text, it's not a shell (an environment to call other tools from) so don't do that, just call uuidgen from shell:

```
$ cat file
foo .*
bar stuff
here

$ xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 printf '%s|%s\n' "$(uuidgen)" < file
5662f3bd-7818-4da8-9e3a-f5636b174e94|foo .*
5662f3bd-7818-4da8-9e3a-f5636b174e94|bar stuff
5662f3bd-7818-4da8-9e3a-f5636b174e94|here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that the real problem here is that you're running a sub-process for each line.  You could read your file explicitly line by line and read output from a batch-uuidgen line by line, and thus only have a single subprocess to handle at once. Unfortunately, uuidgen doesn't work that way.

Maybe another solution?

```
perl -MData::UUID -ple 'BEGIN{ $ug = Data::UUID->new } $_ = lc($ug->to_string($ug->create)) . " | " . $_' $filename > ${filename}.pk
```

Might this be faster?

Comment: Yes this made it a lot faster! Thank you so much